# How to simulate a drop event in gmail's compose window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, inboxsdk

I have a use case where I have to programmatically attach attachments to a Gmail compose window using a chrome extension. [inboxSDK](https://www.inboxsdk.com/) has APIs to do this but I do not want to include a huge library just for this one function.

I tried doing this by simulating a drag and drop event on the compose window. I create a drop event this way:

```
            var fakeDropEvent = new DragEvent('drop');
            Object.defineProperty(fakeDropEvent, 'dataTransfer', {
              value: {files: [blob]}
            });
```

I am giving it a dataTransfer property that has files property with an array of `Blob` objects as value. But dispatching this event on the compose window does not do anything. 
When I tried to catch a normal drop event (one that was manually triggered by a user), I noticed its `event.dataTransfer.files` has a [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) object whereas, for the fake event that I am making, I return an array of blob objects. I am guessing this is the issue that I am facing. Gmail is expecting a `FileList` but does not get it. 
I tried to create a `FileList` object myself but was unsuccessful. Is there any way something like this can be achieved. 
I tried to read what inboxSDK is doing but their code is closed source and it is nearly impossible to understand their uglified code.

Comment: Content scripts run in isolated world so you need to [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your newly created Event has its `isTrusted` property set to false. The browser reads this property and does nothing when you try to dispatch the event to your target node.